# Multiple jQuery plugins not working on the same page

Tags: jquery

I need to use few plugins on each page. One on the left div,middle and right div.But one of them not working whenever another plug in added in. Mostly in my case the 'Mac' style bouncing menu not working. I've tried using jquery noConflict() yet the same.I'm wondering if I'm placing it correctly or any other issue. Any help would be much appreciated as I wasted 2 days wondering on this!

Below is the full page code that I'm facing this issue with.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">

        <script src="menuv2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>

        <style>

  .left {
  height: 100%;

  //opacity: 0.5;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  //border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  //border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  //border-right:3px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
  width: 16%;
  color: #fff;



            }
            .right {
  height: 100%;

 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-left:3px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 float:right;
  width: 16%;
            }
             .middle{
  height: 100%;

background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-right:3px solid #ccc;
  border-left:3px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 3em;
 //margin-right: 1em;
// left:20%;
  width: 60%;


            }

            .ontop
            {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.7em;
 right: 1.6em;



}
.onmiddle {
  position: relative;
  top: 12.7em;
  right: 1.6em;
}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url(bg/6.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;" width="100%" height="100%">




        <div class="left">
            <aside>
                <img src="hooha_images/logo_small.png" class="expand">
            </aside>
            <aside style="padding-top: 20%;" class="ontop">
                <?php
                 include ('sidebar.php');

                ?>   
            </aside>


            <aside>

               <?php include('bottom_left.php');?>
            </aside>

        </div>
        <div class="middle">
           <!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<div id="links">
    <a href="roses/1.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/1.jpg" width='200' height="200" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="roses/2.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/2.jpg" width='200' height="200"  alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="roses/3.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/3.jpg" width='200' height="200"  alt="Orange">
    </a>
    <a href="roses/4.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/1.jpg" width='200' height="200" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="roses/5.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/2.jpg" width='200' height="200"  alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="roses/6.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery>
        <img src="roses/3.jpg" width='200' height="200"  alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>

        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    //var $a=jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#dock2').Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 60,
                    items: 'a',
                    itemsText: 'span',
                    container: '.dock-container2',
                    itemWidth: 40,
                    proximity: 80,
                    alignment : 'left',
                    valign: 'bottom',
                    halign : 'center'
                }
            );
        }
    );

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't need a copy of jquery for each plugin.

Comment: in other words...only load jQuery once, and before all plugins

Comment: Sorry  I don't get it. U mean I'm loading jquery many times? Im very new to Jquery,could you pls explain which exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading jquery twice

Once like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

then again but from elsewhere

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

They will conflict. Load one or the other by removing one. Since you have plugins loading in the head too, you will need to remove the second jQuery include not the first.

If you kept all your JS in the footer this may be more obvious. If you check the console (in Chrome: f12 then click Console) you should see an error.

Comment: Thanks  @popnoodles.I tried removing <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>...Thereafter the second plugin also din't work. Of course  I understand it's coz I removed the related lib. But I can't seem to find a solution..

Comment: Finally I fixed it.

There are 2 ways:

1) I just changed the order of js libs..like placing 

     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

on top of  

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>.

-it worked!

2) I didn't change the order 
But I added this below the second Jquery lib: 
      <script>
        var $old=jQuery.noConflict(true);//must set the value to true else wont work
       </script>

Comment: Ok, but you shouldn't need two versions. Did you try just loading the one from googleapis?

Comment: yes but the other plugin didn't work..I'm not sure how to wrap both in one library.

Comment: Ok, maybe the plugins only work with an older jQuery library. Then you did the right thing with noconflict!